# Find element that goes before target with C++ set

Tags: c++11, binary-search-tree

I know there's `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` method which both find first element that doesn't go before target element, include and exclude the target. But I need a method that can find the last element that goes **before** target. Is there such method or easy way to do this using `set`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just decrement the lower bound?

In general you need to check if the lower bound yields the `begin()` iterator, in which case the element you mention doesn't exist.

Here's some example code (untested, just to give the idea):

```
template<typename T>
std::set<T>::iterator get_last_before(std::set<T> & s, const T & t) {
    auto it = s.lower_bound(t);
    if (it == s.begin()) { throw std::runtime_error(); }
    return --it;
}
```

Comment: tested, exactly the result I want!